# Very confusing while-loop condition

Tags: c, logical-operators, boolean-logic

We have a school task to remove C-comments from a C code file.

There is an approach for this task to go through the input file and loop until the block comment end

```
*/
```

comes.

Why does this code work,

```
while(!(input[i] == '*' && input[i+1] == '/'))
{
  i++;
}
```

But this does not?

```
while(input[i] != '*' && input[i+1] != '/')
{
  i++;
}
```

The second variation never even goes into the loop for some reason. I tried to think around it but couldn't find the cause for why don't they work identically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!(something AND something)` are `NAND` gates, and they can be expressed to `!something OR !something`

So in your case

```
while (!(input[i] == '*' && input[i+1] == '/')) {
```

is the same as

```
//Pick your syntax from these 2 options
while (input[i] != '*' || input[i+1] != '/')
while (!(input[i] == '*') || !(input[i+1] == '/'))
```

---

How *transition* from AND to OR works.

Consider now you have NAND which are AND gates following NOT gates with inputs X and Y. The result is negated AND of both inputs. To separate both inputs to OR, you have to do these steps:

```
     ____      __
x --|    \    |  \
    | AND |---|NOT|--- (NAND)
y --|____/    |__/
```

- Change AND to OR
- Remove NOT by either remove gate or negate output again
- Negate each input separatelly

And then you get:

```
x --- NOT GATE --- \ 
                      -- OR GATE -- NOT (from NAND) -- NOT (negate output)
y --- NOT GATE --- /
```

- If you want to do opposite, you can do it (NOR and AND), just swap OR and AND again and all other steps.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. It just feels too logical to put it in way !something AND !something. Which is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions could be answered by putting them in a truth table

```
while(!(input[i] == '*' && input[i+1] == '/'))
{
  i++;
}
```

produces a truth table of a NAND gate

```
input[i]  input[i+1] Output
    0          0       1  
    0          1       1  
    1          0       1
    1          1       0
```

Whereas

```
while(input[i] != '*' && input[i+1] != '/')
{
  i++;
}
```

produces a truth table of a NOR gate

```
input[i]  input[i+1] Output
    0          0       1  
    0          1       0  
    1          0       0
    1          1       0
```

Now you can easily see why the two while loop produces two different results.

Comment: This clarifies the situation a lot more. Thanks for the table.

Answer (score 0):

The loop test condition has an AND expression where ***the first or left side of the expression is evaluated first*** to see if we need to check the second one also (If it is false, that means we don't need to check the second one as `False && anything = False`).

Here, the first condition is `input[i] != '*'`.
That is why when the character is not * at the beginning of the line, the loop exits at the first execution itself.

Answer (score 0):

it should be OR and not AND,

```
while (input[i] != '*' || input[i+1] != '/')
```

if i is not star * then it cannot be block comment.
if i is star * then if i+1 is not slash '/' then it cannot be block comment.

Answer (score 0):

At the first statement you test...

```
(input[i] == '*' && input[i+1] == '/')
```

When that evaluates to !true you enter the loop. For this to be !true one of your expressions need to fail.

In the second statement you test...

```
input[i] != '*' && input[i+1] != '/'
```

When this evaluates to true you enter the loop. For this to happen you need to both your expressions to success.